# Média (avg) condicional MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tenho a seguinte tabela

```
userid--state-----fraction  
589-----wrong---0,0  
589-----wright---1,0  
589-----wright---1,0  
589-----wrong---0,0  
589-----wrong---0,0  
589-----wrong---0,0  
589-----wrong---0,0  
589-----wrong---0,0  
589-----wrong---0,0  
589-----gaveup--NULL
```

Ao tentar trazer a média usando a query abaixo a linha em que o valor de `state` for `gaveup` não é considerada, por `fraction` ter valor `NULL`:
como posso atribuir valor `0,0` a `fraction` caso o valor `state` seja `gaveup` para obter a média corretamente?

```
SELECT avg(fraction) FROM table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No *mysql* você pode usar o [**ifnull()**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp):

```
SELECT AVG(IFNULL(fraction, 0)) FROM table
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo!

Comment: @MiguelSilva, se resolveu o problema, marca como aceita ;)